# Python3 translate string to date and time in an elegant way

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I was trying to find a good way to translate this string:

*'20171127124906.359599+000'*   - into date/time;

I was currently trying to accomplish this by cutting string into different elements, but the code started to look a bit ugly.

Essentially, my goal is to find a most Pythonic or elegant way to calculate the machines UpTime;

I get this string from WMI, Win32_OperatingSystem class; There are two values that I want to use to calculate the machine UpTime;

```
LastBootUpTime = '20171127124906.359599+000'
LocalDateTime = '20171201151404.691000+000'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Assuming that comes from Powershell, use powershell's built in functionality to convert to a date timestamp that you can import into python.  http://www.itprotoday.com/management-mobility/converting-those-weird-wmi-dates-and-times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal UTC offsets are usually four digits `+HHMM`.  If you can convert your timestamp to that, you can use

```
form datetime import datetime

t = '20171127124906.359599+000'
# I think that your inputs are of the form HHM (So 11:30 would be 113).
# This rounds that out by adding a zero at the end
t = t + '0'

datetime.strptime(t, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%f%z')
```

gives us

```
datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 27, 12, 49, 6, 359599, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

If you want to change that format string, the documentation for it is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)